# Swift: cannot convert value of type 'SomeType<T>' to expected argument type 'SomeType<_>'

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am using generics to build a paging library where I have code similar to this one (simplified):

```swift
struct PageData<T> {
    let item: T
    let pageNumber: Int
}

protocol PagedServiceProvider: class {
    func fetchPage<ItemType>(page: Int, completion: @escaping (PageData<ItemType>?) -> Void)
}


class TestPagedServiceProvider<ItemType>: PagedServiceProvider {
    var pageData: PageData<ItemType>?

    func fetchPage<ItemType>(page: Int, completion: @escaping (PageData<ItemType>?) -> Void) {
        completion(pageData) // COMPILATION ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

the call to `completion(pageData)` produces the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type `PageData<ItemType>?` to expected argument type `PageData<_>?`

This workaround casting with `as?` gets rid of the error:

```swift
class TestPagedServiceProvider<ItemType>: PagedServiceProvider {
    var pageData: PageData<ItemType>?

    func fetchPage<ItemType>(page: Int, completion: @escaping (PageData<ItemType>?) -> Void) {
        completion(pageData as? PageData<ItemType>)
    }
}
```

Also if `var pageData: PageData<ItemType>?` is declared as a local variable inside the `fetchPage<ItemType>...` method, the error is gone as well.

NOTE: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/Dario-Gasquez/ef79cb775e13b8d2cd54d61b220cf951) provides additional context.

I am confused as to why the compiler requires an explicit cast (that looks redundant to me in this case).

Could it be a matter of placeholder types scope (the `ItemType` in the `fetchPage<ItemType>...` method is not the same as the `ItemType` for the `TestPagedServiceProvider<ItemType>` class)?

I tried giving them different names and using where clauses to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me.

```
struct PageData<T> {
    let item: T
    let pageNumber: Int
}

protocol PagedServiceProvider: class {
    associatedtype T
    var pageData: PageData<T>? { get set }
    func fetchPage(page: Int, completion: @escaping (PageData<T>?) -> Void)
}


class TestPagedServiceProvider: PagedServiceProvider {

    var pageData: PageData<String>?

    func fetchPage(page: Int, completion: @escaping (PageData<String>?) -> Void) {
        completion(pageData)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it does solve the compilation error indeed. But I was trying to avoid the use of `associatedtype` due to the additional problems / limitations it introduced. I edited the question to include a [link to this gist](https://gist.github.com/Dario-Gasquez/ef79cb775e13b8d2cd54d61b220cf951) that shows the code in context to help clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code will work for you. I have passed `String` as the Generic type while instantiating the PageData object.

```
func fetchPage<String>(page: Int, completion: @escaping (PageData<String>?) -> Void) {

        let page = PageData<String>(item: "Item", pageNumber: 1)
        completion(page)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for editing this answer; it was by accident and I've rolled it back.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier for the suggestion and sorry for the confusion. I edited the question to clarify that I need a generic implementation. Anyway, I tried your suggestions with a concrete String type like [this](https://gist.github.com/Dario-Gasquez/9697dec311c6925d49508fed3bd2d243) 

But that gets me another error: 
> 'Swift.String' is not convertible to 'String'

Answer (score 0):

Your type signature says that the caller can pass *any* type as ItemType, but then you require the closure to accept a `PageData<String>?`.

`fetchPage` is not actually generic (it can't accept types chosen by the caller), so you can't claim it is. What you mean is to remove the `<ItemType>` and say what you require:

```
func fetchPage(page: Int, completion: @escaping (PageData<String>?) -> Void) {
              ^^                                          ^^^^^^
```

This, however, breaks your PagedServiceProvider protocol, because that protocol requires that TestPagedServiceProvider accept absolutely any ItemType, and it doesn't. You'll need to decide what you really mean. You might mean a protocol with an associated type here, which is a type that the implementation gets to pick rather than the caller.

```
protocol PagedServiceProvider: class {
    associatedtype ItemType
    func fetchPage(page: Int, completion: @escaping (PageData<ItemType>?) -> Void)
}
```

This opens up some headaches, however, since now PagedServiceProvider cannot easily be put in an Array (it's no longer a concrete type). How you deal with this depends heavily on what problem you're actually solving. There is no general solution that is always appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier for your answer and sorry for the confusion. I edited the question to clarify that I am looking for a generic paging library. I tried with `associatedtype` but as you mention it comes with its own problems, so I was trying to avoid using it.

Comment: If you're interested in building a "fetch generic data and parse it" library, see my protocol series. I walk through how to think about the generics step-by-step. https://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol